# Grafana connection with elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, grafana

I have successfully create a connection between Grafana and Elasticsearch. I have already indexed data into Elasticsearch , but Grafana doesn't want to show it as a "Singlestat".

[Elasticsearch Data Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fl3RJ.png)

[Grafana Settings Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZIq3p.png)

So the value is "104". But why Grafana does not show this?

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to show the current value in SigleStat panel you should do it in the following way:

1. In Elastic end - Save it as int, as in SigleStat panel you can show only integers fields.
2. In Grafana end - a. Add "ecommerce" index as data source (located in top left menu - data sources).

   b. In SigleStat panel - "Metrics" tab - choose "ecommerce" data source.

   c. In the query line: write the following "_type:supporttickets".

   d. In Metric field - choose "Max" and "value" (if value is not int you will not see it in dropdown).

   e. In SigleStat panel - "Options" tab - in "Stat" dropdown choose "current".
   More options like colors by thresholds and stuff  - http://docs.grafana.org/features/panels/singlestat/

Answer (score 0):

> Metric -> sum -> is looking for Numeric value but it is getting a string("104").

- Insert the values of ***"@value"*** column as Integer in Elasticsearch

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Stackoverflow is not a forum, please keep the structure of it. This is more a comment than an answer. When you have enough reputation you can post comment.